# sudo error when using nohup to run programs in the background

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sudo, nohup

I have a simple exec running in my terminal to run `program.py` in the background using `nohup`. Here is the script:

```
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
sudo -v
nohup sudo python3 program.py &
killall Terminal
```

It prompts me to enter my password, I do, it accepts the password kills the terminal but the program fails and this error gets appended to `nohup.out`:
`sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

I tried doing

```
sudo -v
nohup sudo -S python3 program.py &
```

but that gives the error

`sudo: no password was provided`

even though I entered the password

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing the command order:

```
sudo nohup python3 program.py &
```

This way is sudo which, after getting the password, launch the nohup command with arguments and disconnects python3 from the terminal, but thinking a bit more, this means that is the sudo command which gets backgrounded, not the nohup command, apart from having to authorize `/usr/bin/nohup python3 program.py` in the sudoers file.

So, to separate the background operation from the rights elevation, create a script `/root/mypylauncher.sh` containing the `nohup python3 program.py &`
command, and call it with `sudo /root/mypylauncher.sh`. (If the script is in a world readable directory, `chown root:root` and `chmod go-w` that script to keep the system safe from malicious hands).